# Copy printers from 1 server to another

Tags: c#, .net, vbscript, printing

We're migrating a bunch of printers from server 2003 to server 2008.  This involves building new server 2008 boxes and decommissioning the older 2003 ones.  There are alot of servers and a lot of printers.  Are there ways to write a vb script or maybe a .net app to copy network printers from one server to another?

Comment: I am writing software to do this, which is a stackoverflow question.

Answer (score 0):

It you have an interest for a software solution you can use `EnumPrinterDrivers` to enumerate a printer drivers `EnumPrinters` to enumerate printers and `EnumPrinterDataEx` to enumerate a printer settings.

You can also use `PrintUIEntryW` function from the **printui.dll**. The function has prototype

```
HRESULT WINAPI PrintUIEntryW(HWND hwnd, HINSTANCE hInst, PWSTR pszParams, INT nShow);
```

(see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/189105 and http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314486). The parameter with parameters like "/ii /f C:\WINDOWS\inf\ntprint.inf" for example can be used to install a printer and some other operations.

You can use `SetPrinter` with level 2 to set printer settings.

If you are searching for some helpful VB-scripts you will find there in the directory `%SystemRoot%\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US`.